# Website showing directory list

Tags: php, apache, filezilla

I'm hosting a website using filezilla. My browser shows me a directory list rather than my index.php page. When i replace the index.php by an index.html, everything is alright.
What should i do in order to access directly to my ondex.php page?

Comment: filezilla is not a webserver

Comment: yes i know that filezilla is just a FTP client. I don't know where to have access to my .htaccess file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `.htaccess` put this code:

```
Options -Indexes
```

It will disable displaying directory list.

Comment: Well, the real problem is , i don't know where to access this file

Comment: You have to create this file if you don't see it.

Comment: Great solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get to the settings for your server.  The default served page needs to be set.
Right now it appears to be index.html.  Simply add index.php to the list.